# Gnuplot-Tikz-TeXstudio setting problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, texstudio, gnuplot

I am a beginner in making graphs of functions by TeX itself - until now i have solved these issues by including .eps pictures. Now i am on doing things better and nicer. I started to use Tikz packages along with official manuals.

My problem now is with plotting functions not included in Tikz "language" (like $x^{4/7}$ or $x*\sin(x)$ for example). I followed the advices on setting up Gnuplot and to allow using external programs.

My system is: Windows vista + TeXstudio + Miktex 2.9, Compiling with Pdflatex.

I have installed Gnuplot 5.0 (what i have never used before), and modified the text

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

in my TeXstudio setting (path: Options->Configure TeXstudio->Commands->Pdflatex) to

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1--enable-write18-interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

according to some advices. However my minimal example still does not work properly...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw plot[id=sin] function{sin(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The compilation proceeds without warnings and errors, however in the output .pdf the graph of the sine function is missing (i printscreened a picture from the .pdf - i cant see possobility for attaching .pdf-s).
[image]

I need an urgent help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your code works for me out of the box (Using gnuplot 5.0 on Linux). Your setup must be still wrong

Comment: If I compile the MWE with `-enable-write18` I get a nice sin-curve. I'm not sure whether some spaces were gobbled in your post, but I suspect there should be a space between "-enable-write18" and "-interaction=nonstopmode", i.e. `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot. Your advice worked also.(like @percusse-s). I am really amazed how on erath so you now these thinks - in my 1165 page long Tikz maual i have about these issues only the following:

Comment: "You must have allowed TEX to call external programs. This is often switched off by default since this is a security risk (you might, without knowing, run a TEX file that calls all sorts of "\bad" commands). To enable this "calling external programs" a command line option must be given to the TEX program. Usually, it is called something like shell-escape or enable-write18. For example, for my pdflatex the option --shell-escape can be given."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a little bit confused about TikZ capabilities and of course the package `pgfplots`. First problem is that you need to let `pdflatex` or whichever engine you are using to reach out the system commands. For example, I use TeXnicCenter and my command line parameters are configured as

```bash
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" -shell-escape
```

The last bit allows for system calls (and the `"%wm"` bit is equivalent to your `%.tex`). And direct compilation of your code gives me

[image]

but I don't have TeXStudio so I couldn't test it. However the idea is essentially the same.

Alternatively you can use TikZ or pgfplots for plotting functions if your function is not really esoteric or complicated.

Here are two examples :

In TikZ you replace one line of your code with

```
\draw plot (\x,{sin(\x r)}) node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
```

And in `pgfplots` with default settings

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmax=6,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
    \addplot[domain=0:4] {sin(deg(x))} node[right]{$f(x)=\sin(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @percusse. Of corse I woud not go for Gnuplot for graphing sine - i knew that it can be handled by Tikz alone (but with $x^r$ wit r not integer Tikz get troubles). The sine-choice was only for simplicity.

Comment: Sorry - i pressed "enter" to early -.... So the realy helpfull passage was your advice where exatly "-shell-escape" should be put. Now my setting for Pdflatex is: is "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1-interaction=nonstopmode %.tex -shell-escape  Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex My pleasure. I don't really encounter any problems with exponentiation using pgfplots. In fact almost always I use it for plotting.

Comment: I think it is because you have already set this shell-escape issue and have Gnuplot installled. Without these, Tikz alone has quite limited list of functions.

Comment: @Alex Give it a try. I don't use any system calling functions and if you don't `pgfplots` doesn't do it for you. So there is no behind the scenes calling which is also not allowed due to security issues. Can you give an example of complicated function?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have no idea what had been wrong before that I decided for Gnuplot. Perhaps the advice in Geogerba (it has a Tikz code exporter): "%<<<<<<<WARNING>>>>>>>
% PGF/Tikz doesn't support the following mathematical functions:
% cosh, acosh, sinh, asinh, tanh, atanh,
% x^r with r not integer

% Plotting will be done using GNUPLOT
% GNUPLOT must be installed and you must allow Latex to call external programs by
% Adding the following option to your compiler
% shell-escape    OR    enable-write18 
% Example: pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex 
"