# What is the most practical way to make and include a plot in pdfLaTeX

Tags: diagrams, plot

I often come to a point, where I want a plot of a set of data or just a simple function to be included into my TeX file. The usual naive approach would be to save the plot as a vector or pixel graphic and just import it with the graphicx package.

But this has a downside. Axeslabels for example are often over or undersized.

So another option I tried is gnuplot and the terminal option epslatex. Although this fixes the problem with the axeslabel writing both a vector graphic file and a tex file I found this method to be very impractical when I wanted to change (a small mistake e.g.) in the axeslabel.

So I wanted to know what is the most practical way of creating and including a plot in a LaTeX file making it compatible with size and font of the pdfLaTeX output?

EDIT: The emphasis lies on plotting data points from a file (not plotting an analytic function, thats just to show some limiting behavior).

Comment: Another user asked a very similar question today http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257833/3235

Comment: Thx...I am more interested in plotting data sets. I only plot functions when I want to show some assymptotic behavior. Is Tikz really suited to plot data points from file?

Comment: Take a look at [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) and `pgfplotstable`

Comment: Can you put a small dataset? It is not possible to estimate what your points look like.

Comment: Doing this with `R` and integrate in your `.tex` document with `Sweave` is perfect for the job. Another option would be `gnuplot` using the `epslatex` terminal.

Comment: Think of a very simple 2 dimensional plot. For example a finite set of points on a quadratic function {0;0}{1;1}{2;4}{3;9} and so on. I am really more interested in general good practice how to implement such a plot in a tex file. I either need to know exactly what font(size) my output of the tex file is and set the plot accordingly or I need something that connects to the output of my tex file (by deciding font(size) when compiling the tex file).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/best-way-to-generate-a-nice-function-graph-in-latex

Comment: thx Joseph Wright, that is what I am looking for. @vaettchen maybe you could elaborate in an answer with a small example. Sounds like a nice way to do it.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to add a sample set instead of descibing it? Font size and other details are not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use gnuplot instead of pgf bundles for some reason, I would suggest you use `tikz` terminal option. Here is the procedure.

First, we must make a `.tex` file which draws a graph you want. Let me plot a sine curve in this demo because I do not have the plotting data. However, you can also do everything you can with gnuplot, including `plot "foo.csv"`. In gnuplot, run the following:

```
set terminal tikz
set output "graph.tex"
set xlabel "set $x$ axis label as you like"
set ylabel "set $y$ axis label as you like"
# put extra settings you want to use here
plot sin(x)
exit
```

We get `graph.tex` where the graph is drawn.

Then all we have to do is include this file in the main source, say `main.tex`. Loading `gnuplot-lua-tikz` package is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\include{graph}
\end{document}
```

However, executing `pdflatex main.tex` somehow generates a error saying `! Undefined control sequence. l.7 \gpsetdashtype{gp dt solid}` This error occurs on TeX Live 2015, not on my previous environment (i.e. TeX Live 2013) and I am afraid I do not know the reason. Anyway, deleting this line 7, we finally get the following:
[image: sine curve]

You can, of course, change the detail of graphs by editing `graph.tex`.

Using [`gnuplottex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex) package might be a good choice although I have never used it.